# How to handle navigation in react-native in response to exceptions in .ts files

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo

We're using Expo and @react-navigation/native-stack. Users have to accept the most recent terms of service in order to use the app. If the terms of use change while the user is logged in, we want to show them an alert and redirect them to the terms of use page.

Our api calls are in separate .ts files, so they can't handle the navigation themselves. We thought about exposing a function in our root navigator that we could then call from the .ts in order to navigate. The advantage is that we could centralize our error handling in the api files, instead of handling it in many different places in the app, where the api is called.

Ideally we'd like to have something like this:

api.ts

```js
export const doSomething = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post(
        'someUrl',
        { someData: 'someData' },
    ).catch((err) => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
            showAlertToNavigateToTermsOfUse();
        }
    })
}
```

The best way we could come up with is to expose a function like this in our root navigator

```js
export const exposedObject = {showAlertToNavigateToTermsOfUse: () => {}}

export default function RootNavigator() {
    const navigator = useNavigation<any>();

    goToTouObj.goToTou = () => {
        Alert.alert('Terms of Use', 'The terms of use have changed, please accept them before continuing', )
        navigator.navigate(ScreenNames.TERMS_OF_USE_SCREEN);
    };
```

This works but seems strange to us, does react-native provide a better way to do this?